# Kubuntu stuck on startup every second time

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 20.10

After upgrading to Kubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10, every second time I boots my system it stops when still showing the Lenovo logo, and every other time it proceeds to the grub boot menu, where I can then select *Ubuntu and it then boots without any further problems.

PC:  Lenovo Thinkpad T490
System: Kubuntu 20.10

Anyone have an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a firmware issue since the problem occurs before anything Ubuntu related has loaded.  Maybe you need to adjust something in your BIOS settings?

Comment: It was fixed by a later kubuntu update, without me having to do anything